# Rotate eps image without the whole page

Tags: graphics, eps, rotating, matlab

I have a eps file printed out from a Simulink model using the Matlab command `print -deps`. However, the image is rotated +90 degrees to portrait. When I include it into my latex document, the whole page becomes rotated -90 degrees.
My command is:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{simulink_model.eps}
  \caption{A Simulink Model}
\end{figure}
```

I tried to add `[angle=90]` but this turns the whole page by 120 degrees.

I guess I could turn the eps source or manually turn the page back in latex. But is there a way to insert a eps file like this one and tell latex to leave the page orientation alone?

Comment: I would think that if you use `angle=-90` you would correct for the `+90` degree portrait turn. No? And shouldn't `90+90=180` which turns your figure up-side down?

Comment: I found out from another post that the rotation is performed in the pdf only. `pspdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None myfile.dvi` prevents it from doing so. But how can I control this mechanism for a single page or eps? @Werner: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you planning on having some landscape and some portrait pages in your document and you want to manually control which is viewed in the appropriate mode?

Comment: By now I have no such pages so I could switch the auto-rotation off. If I had I'd know how to manually turn a page. Only thing what I am wondering about is: how can I prevent a single eps file from turning a page.

Answer (score 2):

the `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` works only on images which are rotated itself, the reason why it should work for the whole document. However you can also try:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \special{ps: gsave -90 rotate }
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{simulink_model.eps}
  \special{ps: grestore }
  \caption{A Simulink Model}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to put an image of some labVIEW code in my thesis. If you're planning to do a single page with landscape content, maintaining the headers, footers, as they are for the rest of the document (unrotated), use the `lscape` package, and put the diagram in

```
\begin{landscape}
<your figure stuff in here>
\end{landscape}
```

and it should look perfect.